# clickable link inside rich:tooltip

Tags: ajax, jsf, richfaces

I have a data table, and on one of the columns, i have tooltip for specific information about the specific rows, now i am trying to place a link inside the tooltip, and that should be clickable (which should navigate to another page),

so here i am unable to click the link inside the tooltip, because when we try to move mouse inside tooltip the tooltip also moving,

and i want the tooltip to be displayed on mouseover as usual and also when i click a specific row that tooltip should stay there and it should allow me to click that link.

can some one help me out for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [`followMouse`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_toolTip.html) attribute to `false`

Comment: Thanks for the replay it works for me. is there any option like when i onclick event on the row the tooltip should be stay displayed and     on mouseover the tooltip should behave normal behaviour?

Comment: what do you mean by "and on mouseover the tooltip should behave normal behaviour" ?

Comment: Normal behaviour means it just displaying the tooltip nothing else. the problem here is, even if i made followMouse=false sometimes i can not able to place mouse on the tootip link because, i place mouse on the 1st row and it is dispaying the tooltip in the 2nd row (the position) in that scenario the it is displaying the 2nd row tooltip, so i wanted to adjust the  position or make visible the tooltip on click.

Comment: You can split your actions: 1) display tooltip for row; 2) do row clickable to redirect on other page.

Comment: @user1742782 not sure I quite understand what behavior you are trying to implement, but if you want the tooltip to appear on click - use showEvent="click".